# How to write a React Stateless Functional Component in Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, create-react-app

I have this:

```
import React, { useReducer } from 'react';
import { Item, List } from '../Types';

type Props = {
    items: List;
};

const TodoList: React.SFC<Props> = ({ items, children }) => {
    return items.map((item: Item) => <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>);
};

export default TodoList;
```

I keep getting:

> Type '({ items, children }: PropsWithChildren) => Element[]' is not assignable to type 'FunctionComponent'.
>     Type 'Element[]' is missing the following properties from type 'ReactElement ReactElement Component)> | null) | (new (props: any) => Component)>': type, props, key

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that you are trying to return an array of elements in your JSX. In React, you can only return a single parent element which then needs to wrap the rest of your elements. So try changing

```
return items.map((item: Item) => <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>);
```

to

```
return (
    <div>
        {items.map((item: Item) => <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>)}
    </div>
)
```

If you would prefer not to have the extra `div`, you can also wrap your list items with a [Fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html). In that case, you would do:

```
return (
    <React.Fragment>
        {items.map((item: Item) => <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>)}
    </React.Fragment>
)
```

Comment: God dam it :)) 

Thank you, makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is type definition of `SFC`: it expects you to return a `ReactElement` or `null`, while you are returning `Element[]`.

```
type SFC<P = {}> = FunctionComponent<P>;

interface FunctionComponent<P = {}> {
  (props: PropsWithChildren<P>, context?: any): ReactElement | null;
  ...
}
```

You can use [React fragments](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
const TodoList: React.SFC<Props> = ({ items, children }) => {
  return (
    <>
      {items.map((item: Item) => (
        <div key={item.id}>{item.id}</div>
      ))}
    </>
  );
};
```